# Eval function or document.write

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the plugin http://tablesorter.com/docs/ for sort my table in javascript and filter the column my problem is that i don't want to put a filter on all the column so for that i use this :

```
           widgetOptions : {
                filter_formatter : {
                    1:function($cellnindx){return null;},
                    4:function($cell,indx){return null;}
                }
            }
```

It's work but now i want to do a script for don't print filter on column who have the class notFiler so I do this script :

```
        var temp = "";
        var i = 0;
        $(".tablesorter th").each(function()
        {
            if($(this).attr('class') == "notFiler")
            {
                if(temp != "")
                {
                    temp += ',';
                }
                temp += i + ': function($cell, indx){return null;}';
            }
            i++;
        });
```

It permit me to gener the text that i permit me to not print the filter on some cloumn but when i do :

```
        widgetOptions : {
            filter_formatter : {
                eval(temp);

            }
        }
```

I have an javascript error : Unexpected token ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use eval. Can't you simply do this instead?

#### First create the result object

```
var widgetOptions = {
    filter_formatter: {};
};
```

#### Now just append to it

```
$(".tablesorter th").each(function(i) {
    if($(this).attr('class') == "notFiler") {
        widgetOptions.filter_formatter[i] = function($cell, indx){return null;};
    }
});
```

#### Then, initialize the tablesorter

```
var tablesorter = $('.tablesorter').tablesorter({
    widgetOptions: widgetOptions
});
```

Comment: I try it so i do that 
               `var i = 0;
  $(".tablesorter th").each(function()
  {
   if($(this).hasClass("notFiler")) 
   {
    tablesorter.widgetOptions.filter_formatter[i] = function($cell, indx){return null;};
   }
   i++;
  });`
where tablesorter is my object but now i have this error :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter_formatter' of undefined

Comment: seems like your `tablesorter.widgetOptions` is undefined, any reason why?

Comment: Heu no I do that : 
`var tablesorter = $(".tablesorter") .tablesorter({
  ...
  widgetOptions : {
                 ...
   filter_formatter : {
   }
  }`
Before insert the code so i don't know.

Comment: @Kvasir can you post your code of how/where you're using the widgetOptions? When do you initialize the tablesorter?

Answer (score 0):

The eval(temp) is in side a JavaScript object, where semi-colons are not allowed to denote the end of the line or item.  As frustrating as it might seem, remove the semi-colon from that line and end the line with out one.

Comment: Already try it but after i have this error : Unexpected token }